# wpa_supplicant returns "Could not read SSID from driver"

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I'm invoking `wpa_supplicant` with `-D nl80211 -i wlp3s0` when I do, immediately I get

```
wlp3s0: Could not read SSID from driver
```

When I use `wpa_cli` and issue a `scan` I get

```
<4>Could not read SSID from driver
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, my underlying card is the

```
Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN
```

This is effectively stopping me from connecting with the new `nl80211` driver. When I use `-Dwext` I no longer get the above but `wpa_supplicant` shows,

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with wpa_supplicant in which I had the same issue. I then used the wpa_gui and it offered an option to start the wifi service, and then worked.

If you still have issues, try testing a different program to interact with network configs, such as wicd-gtk